# how debug sef-hosted alexa skills?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an Alexa skill but I am having problems in a parse inside a method. The problem is only logs look pretty painful for debugging the error. 
When I created using Nodejs and hosted myself, I could get more meaning from console.log().

**Do we have a better way of debugging self-hosted applications?**

I searched but could not find any alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Logs Alexa Hosted Skills](https://developer.amazon.com/it/docs/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html#logs)

> Alexa-hosted skills provide you with a limited view of the AWS console so that you can access information critical to developing your skill. To access the Amazon Cloudwatch logs for your skill, in the lower left corner of the code editor click the Logs: Amazon CloudWatch link, which opens a limited view of the AWS console and provides access to the logs.

Comment: The problem is only logs look pretty painful for debugging the error.

Comment: try to use `JSON.stringify(`${data}`); to debug data in cloudWatch